# Xamarin Forms - HTML text type treats P as BR on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm pulling data from a news feed into my app

The label is set to text type HTML and it renders as expected on iOS with a clean line between paragraphs

However, same markup on Android only gives a line break

Does anyone know why this is?

```
      <Label Text="{Binding CurrentNewsItem.content_html}"
                                   Margin="16,8,16,0"
                                   Grid.Row="3"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   VerticalOptions="Start"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   TextType="Html"
                                   Style="{StaticResource SmallDefaultLabel}" />
```

Feed looks like this

```
      "content_html": "<p>Here is some txt</p>\n<p>Here is some more text</p>",
```

Comment: Sounds like Android has a different opinion about how to space paragraphs. Maybe process the incoming text to replace `</p>\n` with `</p><br>`.

Comment: I tried to add two p tags to the project, and then ran it in iOS, but there was no black line.